# JavaScript - Repleace all occurrences of string

Tags: javascript, text, replace, replaceall, text-formatting

## Question:

I have this:

```
var questionExample0 = "Hi <name>, how are you doing? Well <name>, we have good news for you. <news>"
```

How do I change `<name>` and `<news>` to `Stackoverflow` and `I joined Stackoverflow`? (without using RegExp, [Anchor to question using RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript#1144788))

Comment: In ES6, you'd use a template literal and replace <name> with an appropriate variable. Without ES6... you're left with replace, regexp or not. You'd be far better off using a regexp if not using ES6.

Comment: You could also split/join, but.... meh, that's too hacky for me.

Comment: So what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

//String.prototype.replace with simple regex

```
var questionExample0 = "Hi <name>, how are you doing? Well <name>, we have good news for you. <news>";
questionExample0 = questionExample0.replace(/<name>/gi,'Stackoverflow').replace(/<news>/gi,'I joined Stackoverflow');
console.log(questionExample0);
```

//ES6 literal with variables

```
let name = 'Stackoverflow';
let news = 'I joined Stackoverflow';
var questionExample2 = `Hi ${name}, how are you doing? Well ${name}, we have good news for you. ${news}`;
console.log(questionExample2);
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you are doing as well as showing code.